# multiple return values in callback blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, callback, block

people I am working with don't wanna use delegate methods for a couple of reasons and they want me to come up with a solution;

basically they want a callback block with multiple return values, and when the first return value arrived block should still wait for the upcoming return values

something like

```
[parserobject parsefile:file withCallback {
                if (started) {
                    //file parsing started 
                    //this should get executed first
                }
                //if file parsing succesfully started also check if it 
                //succesfully finished or failed in the same callback
                if (finished) {
                    //file parsing finished 
                }

                if(failed)
                {
                    //this represents if parsing failed any time from start to finish
                    //if so exit the callback

                }
            }];
```

I have seen people using `structs` or `nsintegers` to return different values but usually only one result is returned....

is that above code block possible to written in objective-c?

Comment: You want to be notified for each update ?

Comment: yes, but in the same callback function

Comment: Have you tried `NSNotification` ?

Comment: I would create a block which is called by parsefile whenever the internal state changes. Pass the state as an argument to the block. i.e. block(PARSE_STARTED), block(PARSE_FINISHED), block(PARSE_FAILED)... FINISHED or FAILED indicates finished either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your function

```
typedef void(^VOIDCALLBACK)(void); //Just a type here
typedef void(^BOLLCALLBACK)(bool succeed);//Just a type here
-(void)parserobjectWithFile:(NSString *)file StartCallBack:(VOIDCALLBACK) startCallBack completionBlock:(BOLLCALLBACK) completion{
    // When start
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     startCallBack();//Make call back run in main queue
   });
    //When finisehd set succeed to yes,otherwise set to no
    BOOL succeed = YES;//Pass in to indicator if succeed
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    completion(succeed); //Make call back run in main queue
});
}
```

Then you call it like this

```
   [self parserobjectWithFile:@""
             StartCallBack:^{
                 //Here task is start
             }
           completionBlock:^(bool succeed) {
                //Here task is done.Check succeed to figure out if succeed
           }];
```

**A simple example**

This is the function part

```
@implementation ViewController

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
 [self parserobjectWithFile:@"" StartCallBack:^{
  NSLog(@"start");
 } completionBlock:^(bool succeed) {
   NSLog(@"finished");
 }];
}


typedef void(^VOIDCALLBACK)(void); //Just a type here
typedef void(^BOLLCALLBACK)(bool succeed);//Just a type here
-(void)parserobjectWithFile:(NSString *)file StartCallBack:   (VOIDCALLBACK) startCallBack completionBlock:(BOLLCALLBACK) completion{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //Start
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        startCallBack();//Make call back run in main queue
    });
    sleep(2.0);
    BOOL succeed = YES;//Pass in to indicator if succeed
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        completion(succeed); //Make call back run in main queue
    });
});    
}
@end
```

This will output

```
2015-06-11 23:39:25.426 OCTest[767:144615] start
2015-06-11 23:39:27.426 OCTest[767:144615] finished
```

Comment: hmm yes parse is in the background queue, I didn't exactly understand the part you said `you can do this to let your callBack run on main thread` so callback function calling  `typedef void(^VOIDCALLBACK)(void);`
`typedef void(^BOLLCALLBACK)(bool succeed);` should run in a loop so they never deallocated?

Comment: That is not calling function,`typedef void(^VOIDCALLBACK)(void)` is just a type such as NSObject,NSNumber or something. It will be deallocated when the callback block is done.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write a block that does different things depending on the state reached so far. In order for that to work, declare variables that represent block's state with the `__block` modifier:

```
__block BOOL started = NO;
__block BOOL finished = NO;
__block BOOL failed = NO;
[parserobject parsefile:file withCallback:^ {
    if (started) {
        //file parsing started 
        //this should get executed first
    } else {
        ...
        // Conditionally set started to YES
        started = YES;
    }
    //if file parsing succesfully started also check if it 
    //succesfully finished or failed in the same callback
    if (finished) {
        //file parsing finished 
    }
    if(failed) {
        //this represents if parsing failed any time from start to finish
        //if so exit the callback
    }
}];
```